# Haskell: Perform function for each element in function list parameter

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

There is probably a simple answer to this, but I am new to Haskell. I am trying to iterate through a function parameter and use each list element to call another function. I have a function that performs a move given the game board, the move, and the player number and returns the new game board. Its function header looks like this:

```
play :: [[Char]] -> Char -> Char -> [[Char]]
play gameBoard moveDirection playerSymbol = ...
```

I am trying to call it from a driver function that has the parameters of the initial game board and a list of moves to be performed on the game board. Is there a way to call the `play` function for each element in the move list such that the `gameExample` function below return the game board after every move has been made?

```
moveDirections = "udlrudlr"
gameExample :: [[Char]] -> [Char] -> [[Char]]
gameExample gameBoard (moveDirection : moveDirections) = 
    play gameBoard moveDirection 'p'
```

Please let me know if you require any clarifications.

Comment: Calling a function for each element of the list, feeding each call's output to the input of the next, is known as a *fold*.  See [foldl and foldr](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/GHC-List.html#v:foldl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with explicit recursion:

```
gameExample gameBoard [] = gameBoard
gameExample gameBoard (moveDirection : moveDirections) =
    gameExample (play gameBoard moveDirection 'p') moveDirections
```

Or you can use the `foldl` function to do that for you:

```
gameExample = foldl (\gameBoard moveDirection -> play gameBoard moveDirection 'p')
```

There's also `Data.Foldable.foldl'`, which is usually better for performance than `foldl` is, but you don't need to worry about that for a toy program like this one.

Comment: Also, consider changing the order of the arguments to `play` so that you can simplify the definition to `gameExample = foldl (play 'p')`.